# ¿Cómo validar el tamaño máximo de un archivo adjunto en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando validar el tamaño de las imágenes en el show del controlador de la siguientes maneras:

1)

```
 $validacion = Validator::make($file->all(), [
                     'archivoExamenMedicoDetalle' => 'max:2560',//indicamos el valor maximo
             ]);

             if ($validacion->fails()) 
             {
                 return ('Supera el tamaño máximo permitido.'); 
             }
```

2)

```
$byte = filesize($file);

            $kb = $byte/1024;

            if ($kb >= '2.5') 
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('El archivo supera el tamaño maximo permitido.');</script>";
            }
```

Pero de ninguna manera consigo que pare cuando encuentre un archivo que supera el tamaño máximo. ¿Hay otra manera de validar esto? o ¿Se puede validar al momento de cargar el archivo en el formulario?, ya sea con JavaScript o de otra manera.

Comment: ¿Algún motivo para no realizar las validaciones en el request?

Comment: Desconocimiento para validar el tamaño de un archivo en el request

Answer (score 1):

Al menos en teoría debería funcionarte la validación `size`, según la documentación:

> **size:value**
>
> The field under validation must have a size matching the given value. For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For an array, size corresponds to the count of the array. **For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.**

En ese orden de ideas, la regla de validación quedaría así:

```
'archivoExamenMedicoDetalle' => 'size:2.5',
```

Más información, en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-size